# How to find dates in array?

Tags: php, arrays, date, find

How to find dates in array from certain month?
Array structure is:

```
Array ( [0] => 2013-05-23 
        [1] => 2013-05-24 
        [2] => 2013-05-25 
        [3] => 2013-05-26 
        [4] => 2013-05-27 
        [5] => 2013-06-02 
        [6] => 2013-06-03 
        [7] => 2013-06-04 )
```

I need function that I give array with dates, number of month and it returns array with dates from that month.

Comment: Show us [what you've tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).  See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function narrowByMonth($dates, $monthNumber) {
    foreach ($dates as $date) {
        $split = explode('-', $date);
        $year = $split[0]; // Not needed in this example
        $month = $split[1];
        $day = $split[2]; // Not needed in this example
        if ($month == $monthNumber) {
            echo $date.'<br />';
        }
    }
}

$dates = array ('2013-05-25',
    '2013-05-26',
    '2013-06-02',
    '2013-06-03');

$monthNumber = '05';

narrowByMonth($dates, $monthNumber);
```

Will Output:

2013-05-25
2013-05-26

Comment: Note that this uses `explode` to break up your date into year/month/day. If you use a different format this will need to change. Preferably you should use DateTime objects: php.net/datetime

Comment: I think the easiest way to get the month number is `$month = date('n', strtotime($date));`.

Comment: `strtotime` has a max range of `Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC` and while thats 25 years away, I don't use it still because of the impending depreciation of it. Plus, if you have full error reporting enabled using `strtotime` will cause: `Warning: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings`

Answer (score 2):

I would use the date_parse built in function which returns an array of the date

```
$dates = array(
    0 => '2013-05-23', 
    1 => '2013-05-24',
    2 => '2013-05-25',
    3 => '2013-05-26', 
    4 => '2013-05-27', 
    5 => '2013-06-02', 
    6 => '2013-06-03', 
    7 => '2013-06-04'

);

$date = getDate(05, $dates);

function getDate($month, $dates){
    $return = array();
    foreach($dates as $date){
    $check = date_parse($date);
        if($check['month'] == $month){
            array_push($return, $date);
        }
    }
return $return;
}
```

Comment: +1, I was actually thinking of `strtotime` but `date_parse` is very cool. Nice addition.

Comment: I never knew about `date_parse`, nice!